# With MailMessage, can Disposition-Notification-To be to same as the "To" address?

Tags: .net, email, smtp

So, in the case where I'm testing this functionality, I'm not getting any "Read receipt" when I open a received email (using GMail, BTW).  In my testing scenario, the "from", "to" and notify address (as below) are all the same.  Would this prevent the notification from happening?

```
message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "\"Joe Smith\" <joe@foo.com>");
```

Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, chalk another fail up to browser non-standardization.  Gmail (the client I'm testing with) doesn't support Read Receipts. End Of Story.